# Key detection in canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, keyboard

I tried to draw a simple rectangle and move it by keyboard. But the problem is that I think added everything I need in my code...Well i want to use arrows on keyboard. But before i tried JUST to get an alert....But it does not work.....Help me please... Any help will appreciated.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function Player() {
        this.x=0, this.y = 0, this.w = 50, this.h = 50;
        this.render = function (){
            context.fillStyle = "orange";
            context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        }
      }                
      var player = new Player();

player.x=100;
            player.y= 460;
            setInterval( function() {
                context.fillStyle="black";
                context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
                /*context.fillStyle = "white";
                context.fillRect(100, 460, 30 , 30);*/

                player.render();

                //move all aliens & draw all aliens
                for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    aliens[i].move(),
                    aliens[i].draw(context);
                }
            }, 20);
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event)){
                var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
                alert(event.keyCode + " | " + key_press);

            });
        }
```

Comment: https://github.com/MarkLinus/jsBoard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event)){
----------------------------------------------------^
```

You did put extra parentheses on this, remove it, the actual code would be

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
```